# Windows - Registry Recovery XP

Tags: windows-xp

I am working on an XP machine and gives me the following message just before I log in.

**One of the files containing the systems registry data had to be removed by use of a log or alternate copy. The recovery was successful**

This window always pop up just before I log in and I can log in just fine after pressing okey.

This is what i tried:

- System restore- It wont restore back to a month ago.
- Windows repair- The R option is not available.
- I ran a chkdsk- no results.
- sfc /scannow- no results.
- I had a look in regedit as well. But I am unfamiliar with it.

I noticed a Event ID: 5000 in the event viewer, but the web didn't make sense.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Try running diagnostics on your hard disk using the software provided by the drive's manufacturer. Disk problems are often the root cause of such an error.

Comment: Even better, take this chance to stop using XP. It's not safe.

Answer (score 0):

Backup every thing on your disk, including all your data and perhaps also
an image of your system disk. Ensure that you can restore the image via a boot
CD or USB.

Some tests first :

1. Run [sfc /scannnow](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/43051/how-to-use-sfcexe-to-repair-system-files/) to test system integrity
2. Run chkdsk
3. Boot in Safe mode to see if this happens.

If all checks came up without problems and the same problem occurred on Safe boot,
you could use
[NTREGOPT](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/ntregopt/)
to export the registry contents, then rebuild the actual registry itself,
to fix whatever linkages were broken.